# Build maven project to specific directory

Tags: java, maven, build

I want to package/build my maven project to a specific directory. I tried using:

```
<build>
    <directory>my/path/</directory>
</build>
```

but this creates these following folders under `my/path/`:

- classes
- generated-sources
- maven-archiver
- maven-status

and my jar `myProject.jar` (Without dependencies)

My goal is to get only myProject.jar (Fat/Uber jar) to that directory and nothing else, how can I achieve this? Besides that, I would like to change this jar file's name as well.

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory

Comment: This plugin seems to solve my folder problem, but it creates the jar without dependencies. @tgdavies

Comment: So you're using the maven-assembly-plugin?

Comment: Just tried to use maven-assembly-plugin and it overrides my path which causes to build the jar under `Project-Folder/target/`

Comment: Why do you need to build to specific directory? What is the problem with having the resulting jar in the `target` directory?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to build jar with dependencies.

Example from doc

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

2. You can use [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory) command line option -DoutputDirectory=

or

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>/my/path</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

to output jar into another folder.

3. You can change output file name using maven-jar-plugin

like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>myJar</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or for Maven >= 3

```
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <build>
   <finalName>WhatEverYouLikey</finalName>
 </build>
```

Comment: It creates the jar successfully but the problem is it doesn't build with dependencies. Here's my pom.xml: [link](https://pastebin.com/kg3YEVfw)

P.S. I use `mvn package` to build the jar.

Comment: 1. you will get 2 jar files with this plugin: <your-app-name>.jar and <your-app-name>-jar-with-dependencies.jar
2. All dependencies will be in subfolders in <your-app-name>-jar-with-dependencies.jar